# Writing tabs to a file using PowerShell

Tags: syntax, powershell

I need to echo a series of elements of an array in PowerShell, but provide various delimiters between the elements, so I'm using;

```
    Add-Content -Path $tempInputDir\testoutput.log -value ($($fields[0]) + "   "+
        $($fields[1])  + "    " + $($fields[2]) + " " + $($fields[3])    + "    "+
        $($fields[15]) + "    " + $($fields[17]))
}
```

I need to be able to add tabs and space characters, as you can see from the code above I've just done this by physically adding tabs and spaces in between double quotes, but I'm sure this will cause problems down the line.

What's the correct way to echo these characters to a file? I read somewhere that "'t" could be used, but that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Traditionally it would be \t right?

Comment: @jeffamaphone: In languages that use `\` for escaping characters in strings, yes. Not all languages work that way.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use `` `t `` for a tab character in a double quoted string.  You can also simplify the above to:

```
"$($fields[0])   $($fields[1])   $($fields[2]) $($fields[3])  $($fields[15])  $($fields[17])" | Add-Content $tempInputDir\testoutput.log
```

Comment: The `t escape sequence is what I was looking for.  Note: that is the reversed apostrophe.

Comment: Reversed apostrophe? It is ASCII 96 (0x60). It goes under the names [*backtick*, *backquote*, and *grave accent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming).

Answer (score 28):

To join the nominated fields together with tabs:

```
[string]::join("`t", (0..3,15,17 | % {$fields[$_]}))
```

Comment: That is a beautiful one liner. Just makes me smile.

Comment: while you're at it: [string]::join("`t", (0..3,15,17 | % {$fields[$_]}))