# How to add a tab to a text file

Tags: powershell, text, format

I am running a `for` loop that would query for certain services and then output the services and their selected properties to a text file on each separate line where each property is separated by a tab, but I haven't figured out how to add a tab to a text file.

For instance, this is current set of strings in my code:

```
write-output $server, $servicename, $status, $startname | out-file -append output.txt
```

I would like to append the above string to **output.txt**, so it would appear like this:

```
server1 <tab> servername <tab> status <tab> startname
server2 <tab> servername <tab> status <tab> startname
```

Answer (score 6):

**"`t"** will output a tab character.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
"{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}" -f $server, $servicename, $status, $startname |
    Out-File "C:\path\to\output.txt" -Append
```

If your input data is a list of objects, you may also be able to use `Export-Csv` or `ConvertTo-Csv`:

```
... | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation |
    Out-File "C:\path\to\output.txt" -Append
```

Comment: Great that helps. Thank you for the extra example on ConvertTo-CSV cmdlet

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer (click the check mark below the number to the left of the answer to accept, and the arrow above the number to upvote).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can use  ``t` for tab in PowerShell. See Stack Overflow question *[Writing tabs to a file using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671965)*.

Most languages support `\t` though.

Answer (score -1):

Even more flexibility is given working with arrays.

Let's say you've put your information in an array.

```
$servers[] = array($server, $servicename, $status, $startname);
```

Then you can implode the values with a tab, like this:

```
foreach($servers as $server)
  echo implode("\t", $server) . "\n";
```

Comment: Which language is that supposed to be? This is not PowerShell syntax. Looks more like PHP to me.